# How do I see Facebook Share, Twitter Tweet, and Google Plus share counts if I don't display the statistic?

Tags: facebook, twitter

On my site, I am using a custom Facebook Share, Twitter Tweet, and Google Plus share buttons; however, I am not displaying the # of shares to the user. As a web admin, how can I see share stats without obviously showing them on the front-end to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can view +1 statistics in your Google Webmaster Tools (Dashboard->Traffic->+1 Reports):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-impact?hl=en&siteUrl=YOURURLHERE

For Facebook, you can view "Facebook Insights." More info here:

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=122126631202357#How-do-I-see-Insights-for-my-website?

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=204330989603519#What-metrics-are-available-through-the-Insights-API?

Perhaps someone else can chime in with information on Twitter.